# Installing FluentNHibernate creates conflicts between different versions of "NHibernate"

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nuget-package

This are the warnings I get:

```
Found conflicts between different versions of "NHibernate" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "NHibernate, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" and "NHibernate, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4".
    "NHibernate, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" was chosen because it was primary and "NHibernate, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" was not.
    References which depend on "NHibernate, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" [C:\Daten\RadSvn\CSharp Projekte\VSPRECH\packages\NHibernate.5.3.3\lib\net461\NHibernate.dll].
        C:\Daten\RadSvn\CSharp Projekte\VSPRECH\packages\NHibernate.5.3.3\lib\net461\NHibernate.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Daten\RadSvn\CSharp Projekte\VSPRECH\packages\NHibernate.5.3.3\lib\net461\NHibernate.dll".
            NHibernate, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4, processorArchitecture=MSIL
    References which depend on "NHibernate, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" [].
        C:\Daten\RadSvn\CSharp Projekte\VSPRECH\packages\FluentNHibernate.3.3.0\lib\net461\FluentNHibernate.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Daten\RadSvn\CSharp Projekte\VSPRECH\packages\FluentNHibernate.3.3.0\lib\net461\FluentNHibernate.dll".
            FluentNHibernate, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880, processorArchitecture=MSIL
Found conflicts between different versions of "NHibernate" that could not be resolved.
There was a conflict between "NHibernate, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" and "NHibernate, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4".
    "NHibernate, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" was chosen because it was primary and "NHibernate, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" was not.
    References which depend on "NHibernate, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" [C:\Daten\RadSvn\CSharp Projekte\VSPRECH\packages\NHibernate.5.3.3\lib\net461\NHibernate.dll].
        C:\Daten\RadSvn\CSharp Projekte\VSPRECH\packages\NHibernate.5.3.3\lib\net461\NHibernate.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Daten\RadSvn\CSharp Projekte\VSPRECH\packages\NHibernate.5.3.3\lib\net461\NHibernate.dll".
            NHibernate, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4, processorArchitecture=MSIL
    References which depend on "NHibernate, Version=5.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4" [].
        C:\Daten\RadSvn\CSharp Projekte\VSPRECH\packages\FluentNHibernate.3.3.0\lib\net461\FluentNHibernate.dll
          Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Daten\RadSvn\CSharp Projekte\VSPRECH\packages\FluentNHibernate.3.3.0\lib\net461\FluentNHibernate.dll".
            FluentNHibernate, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8aa435e3cb308880, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

I seems like there are 2 Versions of nHibernate refered in my solution:

- nHibernate 5.3.0.0
- nHibernate 5.4.0.0

The problem is: I did not install nHibernate by myself. I installed only the "Latest stable 3.3.0" FluentNHibernate with the NuGetManager which will itself install nHibernate 5.3.0.0 in the background.

Is there something wrong with nuGet in combination with FluentNHibernate? It seems like the package has a dependency to nHibernate 5.3.0.0 while the FluentNHibernate.dll is linked to the newer nHibernate 5.4.0.0?

What should I do? On the surface everything seems to work. Should I ignore the warning or is there a way to resolve this?